# React - Applying CSS class when scrolled to a certain target element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to apply a CSS class upon a user scrolling to a particular target element. I've written a helper function here:

```
export function isTriggerElementInViewport(elementId) {
    const element = document.getElementById(elementId)
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect()

    const viewportWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth
    const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight

    return (rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= viewportHeight &&
        rect.right <= viewportWidth)
}
```

And my React component is:

```
const MyComponent = () => {  
    const [elementVisible, setElementVisible] = useState(false)

    const _handleScroll = elementId => {
        console.log('Scrolling')
        setElementVisible(isTriggerElementInViewport(elementId))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => _handleScroll('targetElementId'))
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className={elementVisible ? 'special-class' : ''} id="targetElementId">
            When this is visible, apply the special CSS class.
        </div>
     )
}
```

I've written a console log in the handle scroll listener and it does not get called when I scroll. To clarify: I am scrolling the window of the page and when I get to a certain element, I want a CSS class to be applied.

How do I achieve this behavior?

Note: I would prefer ideas/solutions that does not involve JQuery or other external libraries as many of the other answers about this tends to do.

Comment: you define `_handleScroll` but you are calling `_handlePartnerScroll`. it works if you fix this

Comment: @buzatto Apologies. That was leftover from when I was trying to simplify the code for SO purposes. My issue still exists.

Comment: I reproduced in a sandbox before my comment and it worked as expected. the issue seems unrelated to the code itself. Something else affects your ability to attach events to window

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simluate you in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-5tw7t?file=/index.js:0-1229

I don't see any problem with it. You can check the console log and inspect at developer tool to see the class is toggled when you scrolled there